# Read/Unread News

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have made a function to laravel project to post news, if a user open a new then I add to table the newid and userid so I will know who open it, now I want to display in bold the unread news I try with a relationship but I didnt manage to do it

my model News

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Auth;

class News extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;

  protected $fillable = [
    'titles',
    'content',
    'user_id',
    'filename',
    'publish',
    'category',
  ];
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

  public function users() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');

   }
  public function readnew() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Readnews','user_id',Auth::user()->id);

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error messages? What's the output of the current relationship?

Comment: no error, I get correct details but the relationship is null

Comment: Your `readnew` is trying to retrieve news that has already been read. You need to exclude newid already in the table to find unread news.

Comment: and how to filter userid?

Comment: I suggest you do this outside of relationship, as you need to find all newid not in Readnews.